# Check if a string contains a certain number

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

```
8,7,13,14,16
```

Whats the easiest way to determine if a given number is present in that string?

```
$numberA = "13";
$string = "8,7,13,14,16";

if($string magic $numberA){
$result = "Yeah, that number is in there";
} else {
$result = "Sorry.";
}
```

Looking for magic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<?php 
in_array('13', explode(',', '8,7,13,14,16'));
?>
```

…will return whether '13' is in the string.

Just to elaborate: explode turns the string into an array, splitting it at each ',' in this case. Then, in_array checks if the string '13' is in the resulting array somewhere.

Comment: Just to elaborate: `explode` turns the string into an array, splitting it at each ',' in this case. Then, `in_array` checks if the string '13' is in the resulting array somewhere.

Comment: this works too well aparently, returns true if the subject is 13, and the target contains a 1 or a 3, not just the whole subject itself.

Comment: No, patrick, it won't. exploding the sample string like in this answer, generates the array `array('8','7','13','14','16')`.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, that might be more efficient for laaaaaaaarge strings, is using a regexp:

```
$numberA = "13";
$string = "8,7,13,14,16";

if(preg_match('/(^|,)'.$numberA.'($|,)/', $string)){
    $result = "Yeah, that number is in there";
} else {
    $result = "Sorry.";
}
```

Comment: That will also match `1,2,113`.

Comment: vava's way is probably a bit faster. If you're familiar with regexes, mine might be more self-explanatory, since it describes what we accept, instead of changing the input.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (strpos(','.$string.',' , ','.$numberA.',') !== FALSE) {
    //found
}
```

Notice guard ',' chars, they will help to deal with '13' magic '1, 2, 133' case.

Comment: But what about at the end, where it doesn't have a comma behind the number?

Comment: That's why I also added comma to the haystack string :)

Comment: Nice. Somehow it never occured to me to concat a comma to the original string. I used a regex instead :F

Comment: As you said yourself: “13 is a part of 113” and `13,` is part of `113,`.

Comment: Like my first submission, this will fail if the last number is 113. Concat a comma at the start of each string to fix =)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you match the full number in the string, not just part of it.

```
function numberInList($num, $list) {
    return preg_match("/\b$num\b/", $list);
}
$string = "8,7,13,14,16";    
numberInList(13, $string); # returns 1
numberInList(8, $string); # returns 1
numberInList(1, $string); # returns 0
numberInList(3, $string); # returns 0
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple string search should do if you are just checking to find existence of the string. I dont speak php but i think this is how it could be done.

```
$mystring = '8,7,13,14,16';
$findme   = '13';

if (preg_match('/(?>(^|[^0-9])'.$findme.'([^0-9]|$))/', $mystring)) {
    $result = "Yeah, that number is in there";
} else {
    $result = "Sorry.";
}
```

Comment: simple search is not enough. 13 is a part of 113 :)

Comment: See vava's answer for the proper way =)

Comment: Oh yeah i dint think of that. Hmm Then i guess the explode technique answer or maybe using regex would be a faster way

Comment: @Jass, both probably slower, but explode looks better and more maintainable. Regexp is generally slow and explode will create and iterate over array. Also, guards can be pre-added, making it even faster :)

Comment: On the other hand, original string can be pre-converted to associative array, this is the fastest way possible.

Comment: Something like /(?>[^0-9]$the-number-to-be-found[^0-9])/ could be fast enough i guess? Ofcourse explode would be better if i needed all those other numbers to do something.

Comment: It's fast enough but just not as fast as simple substring search :)

Comment: Alrite. Modified my answer. Dint want a buggy answer there. Thanks.

Comment: What if the number is the first or last? Then either the first or second `[^0-9]` will fail.

Comment: Now it is way too similar to gnud's answer. I guess i should remove my answer. Its useless anyway.