# Why does Ruby include? evaluate to nil?

Tags: ruby

So, I'm a total nuby working through http://www.rubykoans.com/ and I'm stuck on about_scoring_project.rb.  This is my stab at the score method.

```
def score(dice)
  score = 0;
  if dice.respond_to?("include?") then
    # add 1000 points if rolled 3 ones
    score += 1000 if dice.include?([1, 1, 1])

    # add 100 points times die face value if rolled 3 of a number between 2 and 6
    (2...6).each do |die|
        score += die*100 if dice.include?([die, die, die])

      # award points for each 1 or 5 not a part of a set of 3
      leftovers = dice - [1,1,1]
      leftovers -= [5,5,5]
      leftovers.each do |leftover|
        score += 100 if leftover == 1
        score += 50 if leftover == 5
      end
    end
  end
  score
end

class AboutScoringAssignment < EdgeCase::Koan
  def test_score_examples
    assert_equal 1150, score([1,1,1,5,1])
    assert_equal 0, score([2,3,4,6,2])
    assert_equal 350, score([3,4,5,3,3])
    assert_equal 250, score([1,5,1,2,4])
  end
end
```

In the call to score from the first assert_equal, I would expect dice.include?([1,1,1]) to evaluate to true, but it's evaluating to nil (and score is returning 0 instead of 1150).

I tried this separately...

```
require 'test/unit'

class EnumerableTests < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_include
    my_enumerable = [1,1,1,5,1]
    assert true, my_enumerable.include?([1,1,1])    
  end
end
```

...and the test passes, so I don't know why I'm getting nil in my score method.

Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Good question, but duplicate of [Determining whether one array contains the contents of another array in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855174/determining-whether-one-array-contains-the-contents-of-another-array-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor nitpick: `Array#include?` always returns `true` or `false`, never `nil`.

To answer your question: `x.include?(y)` tests whether `y` is an element of `x`, not whether it's a subarray.

`[1,1,1,5,1].include?([1,1,1])` returns `false` because `[1,1,1]` is not an element of the array `[1,1,1,5,1]`. `[[1,1,1],[5,1]].include?([1,1,1]))` would return `true`.

There is no method in ruby that checks whether an array is a subarray of a another array, but you can easily write it as `arr1.each_cons(arr2.size).include?(arr2)` (needs `require 'enumerator'` in 1.8.6). This is `O(arr1.size*arr2.size)` though.

If you want it in `O(arr1.size + arr2.size)`, you can implement the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris-Pratt_algorithm) (which is meant to find substrings, but works equally well for finding subarrays as they are essentially the same thing).

Comment: Thanks...I'm getting the idea that it's returning nil from the RubyMine debugger.  Maybe I don't understand the debugger, or maybe it's a RubyMine bug.

Comment: Thanks for the arr1.each_cons(arr2.size).include?(arr2) suggestion - works great for me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what `Array#include?` does. It searches for its argument as an element of the array, not as a subsequence. Your `test_include` will always pass, because you give the `assert` function `true` as its first argument. You should either use `assert_equal` with these arguments or (preferably) just get rid of the first argument.