# comparing sequences in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, compare

Assuming I have to (small-to-medium) arrays:

```
tokens = ["aaa", "ccc", "xxx", "bbb", "ccc", "yyy", "zzz"]
template = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

How can I determine whether `tokens` contains all entries of `template`, in that same order?

(Note that in the example above, the first "ccc" should be ignored, resulting in a match due to the last "ccc".)

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You say `in that same order?` and then say `the first "ccc" should be ignored, resulting in a match due to the last "ccc".` so is order important or not? I've given you a very simple answer for both scenarios

Comment: Good question +1, see my answer for one-line condition to check your data.

Comment: Sorry for the amiguity; the order is indeed significant - however, the first "ccc" is insignificant because it doesn't match the template's order (whereas the second "ccc" does). So by that I meant to illustrate the possibility of duplicates messing things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleanest, I think, to do this via recursion:

```
class Array
  def align(other)
    if pos = index(other.first)
      other.size == 1 || slice(pos..-1).align(other.drop(1))
    end
  end
end
```

so:

```
[1,2,3,4,3,2,1].align([1,2,3])
=> true
[1,2,3,4,3,2,1].align([1,4,1])
=> true
[1,2,3,4,3,2,1].align([1,4,2,3])
=> nil
```

Comment: I like that! It's similar to manatwork's solution, but more concise. It doesn't seem to pass my test cases though, so will have to investigate further...

Comment: What's a test case that doesn't pass?

Comment: Never mind, I was being stupid (rewrote yours as an independent function, as I don't like extending Array if I don't have to) - so it seems to work great, and since it's my favorite solution, I have accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

This works for your sample data.

```
tokens = ["aaa", "ccc", "xxx", "bbb", "ccc", "yyy", "zzz"]
template = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

pos = 0
condition_met = true
template.each do |temp|
  if (tpos = tokens[pos..-1].index temp) == nil then
    break condition_met = false
  else
    pos = tpos
  end
end

puts condition_met
```

Comment: you could remove the else part and use `if (pos = tokens[pos..-1].index temp) == nil then`

Comment: @thorsten müller, you are right. I forgot that after restructuring the condition.

Comment: This is rather clever, and seems to work too (will write some unit tests to confirm) - thanks a bunch!

Comment: It's too complicated. Just subtract one array from the other. Much simpler

Comment: jamesw: Substracting arrays does not take order into account.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **one-liner** condition:

```
 tokens.select {|t| t if template.include?(t)}.reverse.uniq == template.reverse \
  or \
   tokens.select {|t| t if template.include?(t)}.uniq == template
```

Example:

```
def check_order(tokens, template)
   tokens.select {|t| t if template.include?(t)}.reverse.uniq == template.reverse \
    or \
     tokens.select {|t| t if template.include?(t)}.uniq == template
end

tokens = ["aaa", "xxx", "bbb", "ccc", "yyy", "zzz"]
template = ["bbb", "aaa", "ccc"]
check_order(tokens,template) # => false

tokens = ["aaa", "ccc", "xxx", "bbb", "ccc", "yyy", "zzz"]
template = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
check_order(tokens,template) # => true

tokens = ["aaa", "ccc", "xxx", "bbb", "ccc", "yyy", "zzz"]
template = ["aaa", "ccc", "bbb"]
check_order(tokens,template) # => true
```

Comment: This return false for the original data, while should return true.

Comment: Thanks - however, while this passes my current tests, the `reverse` suggests there's a dangerous assumption. Indeed, if my original `template` becomes `["aaa", "ccc", "bbb"]`, this no longer returns the expected value (`true`).

Comment: I'm sorry, that was not too clear in your question. You said "the first "ccc" should be ignored", then I thought only the last occurrence was relevant in the tokens order.

Comment: I've updated the answer with expanded one-liner, which will manage the last case you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but - please correct me if I'm wrong - that still seems to assume a certain order; if "ccc" appeared more than three times and the significant occurrence was in the middle, that would not be discovered?

Comment: Tested with this last use case you mentioned the result is still correct.

Comment: Indeed, I can't seem to make that fail - which somehow baffles me. I'll need to dig deeper, come up with some more complex test cases (still skeptical, unfortunately). In the meantime, thank you and have an upvote!

Comment: Yes, you can test it against much complex situations and see if your requirements are still satisfied. It's still hard to me understand what should be the wanted result in messy cases like `tokens = ["aaa", "ccc", "xxx", "bbb", "ccc", "yyy", "bbb", "zzz"]` and `template=["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]` for which my solution returns `false`.

Comment: The case you mention should return true, because the template `sequence` is contained within `tokens` (it doesn't seem messy to me, but I understand that might be due to context - perhaps think of it like this: does the sentence `tokens` contain the sequence `template`, allowing for any number of tokens in between).

Answer (score 2):

Solution provided by manatwork is good, but here is one that seems more ruby-ish to me:

```
tokens = ["aaa", "ccc", "xxx", "bbb", "ccc", "yyy", "zzz"]
template = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

def tokens_include_template(tokens, template)
  tokens = tokens.to_enum
  template.each do |t|
    return false unless loop { break true if t == tokens.next }
  end
  true
end

puts tokens_include_template(tokens, template)
```

Comment: Frankly, I find this harder to understand - but that might well be personal preference. Thanks though, I'll take it under consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea, if the arrays are small-to medium, it might work fine.
It just converts the tokens into a regexp and tries to match the template against it.
(This will also treat empty template as if it matches tokens, so if you don't want that, just handle this corner case explicitly)

```
def tokens_in_template? tokens, *template
  re = /^#{tokens.map {|x| "(?:#{x})?"}.join}$/
  !! (template.join =~ re)
end

tokens = ["aaa", "ccc", "xxx", "bbb", "ccc", "yyy", "zzz"]
puts tokens_in_template? tokens                            # => true
puts tokens_in_template? tokens, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"       # => true
puts tokens_in_template? tokens, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aa" # => false
puts tokens_in_template? tokens, "aaa", "zzz", "ccc"       # => false
puts tokens_in_template? tokens, "aaa", "zzz"              # => true
```

Comment: Indeed, a colleague also just suggested using regular expressions, which works because each token has (or, in the example here, effectively constitutes) a unique ID: `source = tokens.map { |t| "-#{t.id}-" }.join(""); pattern = template.map { |t| "-#{t.id}-" }.join(".*"); pattern = Regexp.new(pattern); return pattern.match(source)` (unfortunately, I can't put this into a proper answer due to Stack Overflow restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the first array from the second array if the result is empty you have your match

```
result = template - tokens
if result.empty?
  #You have a match
else
  #No match
end
```

Read more about arrays here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000273

If order is important then use <=> operator again described in the link above

Comment: Ooops! You are right. I read the question as being order not important.

Comment: I read that right. Order is not importenat read the note `(Note that in the example above, the first "ccc" should be ignored, resulting in a match due to the last "ccc".`

Comment: So this will do exactly the job

Comment: No, tokens still need to contain template's items in right order. It shouldn't match if you remove the second 'ccc' from tokens, as far as I got it.

Comment: But the note sais that that's not true. The note clearly states that fact that even though 'ccc' is in the wrong order the arrays should still match! The question is ambiguous and needs clarifying, but I have given a solution for both scenarios so what's with the down vote?

Comment: First 'ccc' is not important, because there is second one. But yes, question does need clarifying. P.S. I didn't vote down.

Comment: This is too confusing :) No worries @Victor Deryagin

Comment: I have (hopefully) clarified above that order is significant.