# Check if a string contains a specific number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

I want to check if a string contains a specific number in JavaScript, how can I rewrite the statement `s contain d` in below code?

```
var s = '11/14/2012';
var d = '14';
if (s contain d) {
    //...
}
```

My case is similar to [Check if a string contains a certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553462/check-if-a-string-contains-a-certain-number), but how can I implement this action in JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+string+contains

Comment: Might want to check using slashes to bound your value so you don't get false matches on the month or year if you're looking for the day as Syuaa mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: @elclanrs You mean `~s.indexOf(d)` right?

Comment: @Jack there's no need to coerce to boolean (with `!!` or otherwise) in an `if` condition.

Comment: @Jack: That would be the case for a `return !!~s.indexOf(d)` for example.

Comment: @elclanrs I meant that you reversed the logic in your earlier comment.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah it should be `if (~s.indexOf(d))`

Answer (score 3):

The easier way is to use index Of.

```
if(s.indexOf(d) > -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = '11/14/2012';
var d = '14';
if (s.match(d)) {
   alert('Found');
}​
```