# Best way to check if a number contains another number

Tags: javascript

For example if the number 752 contains the number 5? Whats the best way to check? Convert to string or divide into individual digits?

Comment: looking for a number in a number - string ... looking for a digit in a number - string or individual digits

Comment: I would convert it to a string, and do a regex match on it: `(752).toString().match(/5/)`

Comment: Have you tried anything? And define "best".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a string contains a specific number in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372958/check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-number-in-javascript)

Comment: if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Comment: @AmmarCSE Thanks your answer solved it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Convert to string and use indexOf

```
(752+'').indexOf('5') > -1
```

```js
console.log((752+'').indexOf('5') > -1);
console.log((752+'').indexOf('9') > -1);
```

Comment: The `.` operator has higher precedence than `+`, so you need parentheses for this to really work.

Comment: You have a problem in your operator precedence. It should be `(752+'').indexOf('5')`, otherwise `''.indexOf('5')` will evaluate first.

Comment: A Regex would also be an order of magnitude less efficent @Nick

Answer (score 3):

Convert to `string` and use one of these options:

`indexOf()`:

```
(number + '').indexOf(needle) > -1;
```

`includes()`:

```
(number + '').includes(needle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3 ways:

1. Check it by string contains:

   ```
   var num = 752;
   num.toString().indexOf('5') > -1 //return true or false - contains or not
   ```
2. Check by loop

   ```
   var f = 2;
   while(num > 0 ){
     if( num % 10 == f){
       console.log("true");
       break;
     }
     num = Math.floor(num / 10); 
   }
   ```
3. Check by regular expressions

   ```
    num.toString().match(/5/) != null //return true if contains
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkNumberIfContainsKey(number, key){
    while(number > 0){
        if(number%10 == key){
            return true;
        }
        number = Math.trunc(number / 10);        
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(
  checkNumberIfContainsKey(19, 9),   //true
  checkNumberIfContainsKey(191, 9),  //true
  checkNumberIfContainsKey(912, 9),  //true
  checkNumberIfContainsKey(185, 9)  //false
);
```

The most efficient solution among available answers because of the complexity of this program is just `O(number of digits)` if `number = 10235` then the `number of digits = 5`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "some" function.
"Some"thing like this:

```
    function hasFive(num){
         return num.toString().split("").some(function(item){
          return item === "5";
         }); 
    }
```

and then you can call it:

```
   hasFive(752)
```

Further improved is that you make a function that takes number and digit you want to check:

```
       function hasNumber(num, digit){
             return num.toString().split("").some(function(item){
                 return item == digit;
             }); 
        }
```

And then call it in similar way:

```
hasNumber(1234,3) //true
hasNumber(1244,3) //false
```

So that way we can check any number for any digit. 
I hope so "some"one will find this useful. :)